# Could you tell me what the preposition "off" mean?

Tags: prepositions

The forum is located on Musavi St. **off** Taleghani Ave.

I am wondering what the bold part could mean here.

Comment: Nima, a dictionary can help here. The meaning of the *preposition* - **off** - means **leading away from something or near to something**. Does that help?

Comment: If pictures help, here is a pictorial description for you. Go to this [link](http://www.ancientpath.net/Bible/Resources/NT_Resources/res_preposisitions.htm).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's take a look at this set of directions, found on Mapquest:

> 1215 Lambda Drive, (just off of Murray Street)

Here is the accompanying map:

[image]

When we say that one street is just off another, it means that they intersect. Usually the smaller road is said to be off the major road, rather than the other way around. (In other words, I might say that Lambda Drive is off Murray Street, but I'd be unlikely to say that Murray Street is off of Lambda Drive.)

We often talk about roads in this way to help give us a sense of location. I might have a conversation like this with my son:

> Dad, can you drop me off at Jake's house tonight?
> Where does he live?
> He lives on Mulberry Street.
> Where's that?
> It's off of Banner Drive.

If you overheard that conversation, you could assume that Banner Drive is a fairly well-known road, and that somewhere along that road it intersects Mulberry Street.

If Mulberry Street street didn't intersect with Banner Drive, but was close by, my son might say:

> It's in a neighborhood off of Banner Drive.

Also, in this context, the *of* is optional. Therefore, both of these are the same thing:

> Maple Avenue is off of Elm Street.
> Maple Avenue is off Elm Street.

Here are directions from a [website](http://www.webstertheater.com/about/directions/):

> The Webster Theatre is located at:
>
> 31 Webster Street
> Hartford, CT
> Located in Barry Square, just off Maple Avenue

Answer (score 1):

The forum is located on Musavi St. off Taleghani Ave.

"Off" is a preposition in the sentence, meaning a short distance away from or near to Taleghani Avenue; of course, it's not attached to the Avenue.

Comment: It may not be "attached", but chances are they intersect.